# Equality Comparison

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript  version Version 4.7.3.
I am using the Equality Comparison with number and string.Below is the code

```ts
let a:number = 10;
let result = a=='10';
```

I am getting below compilation error.

This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug (see [#26592](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26592)); basically, `==` and `===` are treated the same for the purpose of this error message. To be clear, the bug is that the error message is wrong.

Typescript is supposed to be [strongly-typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), so the use of type coercion is discouraged, even though it's valid in Javascript. If you want to compare a number and a string, then (from Typescript's perspective) instead of writing `n == s`, you should write `String(n) === s` or `n === Number(s)`; or, make the two variables the same type in the first place.

So, a better error message would be something like *"`==` operator on types `number` and `string` may be a mistake"*, although in my opinion, you just shouldn't use `==` at all.